# Changing text displayed in the 'textbox' visual using powerbi-client embed API

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to change the text displayed in the textbox after adding visual. See code below.

Based on the documentation I can only interact with the [Visual Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/visual-properties) or [Data Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/data-fields).

The **textbox** visual does not have any data roles when I am running `getCapabilities()` on it. In the visual properties list, the titleText seems to be the property I am looking for, but it does not change anything.

To give some context why I need this.
I am trying to build a form, where I can add extra visuals to an already existing PowerBI report, and I need the abilty to also set some basic formatted text there to have a nicely looking layout

```js
    const pages = await report?.getPages()

    const activePage = pages?.filter(function (page: any) {
      return page.isActive
    })[0]

    const visualResponse = await activePage?.createVisual(
      'textbox',
      {
        displayState: {
          mode: models.VisualContainerDisplayMode.Visible,
        },
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
      },
      true,
    )

    visualResponse?.visual.setProperty(
      {
        objectName: 'title',
        propertyName: 'titleText',
      },
      {
        value: 'Some text to display',
      },
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with the `titleText` propertyName, We also need to set the `visible` propertName to be true for title to be visible.

Refer to the below code.

```
visualResponse?.visual.setProperty(
    {
        objectName: 'title',
        propertyName: 'titleText',
    },
    {
        value: 'Some text to display',
    },
)
visualResponse?.visual.setProperty(
    {
        objectName: 'title',
        propertyName: 'visible',
    },
    {
        value: true,
    },
)
```

References:

[title-PropertyNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/visual-properties#:%7E:text=Boolean-,title,String,-legend)

[Properties-API](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/visual-properties#properties-apis)

Comment: You were correct, that applies to the title text. However, it works slightly differently than I expected. My goal is to be able to insert and format text in the textbox (its value).

I think I could just use the title property, but this won't allow me to use the partial formatting